# Cordova on Android navigator.notification.confirm callbacks stuck in queue

Tags: android, cordova

This is a bit of a long shot but I'm going to ask to see if others have experienced anything similar.

We are creating a cordova ( 3.3.0 )  iOS / Android app. On iOS all is well. 
On Android ( testing with Android emulators or a Samsung 8 Tab 4.2.2 ) when  navigator.notification.confirm is called we quite often see the callback not fired back in JS after one of the confirm dialog buttons has been pressed.

Debugging Cordova ( native side ) we see the button pressed, the native dialog dismissed and the callback message added to the JsMessageQueue. But the queue doesn't seem to be serviced until something else forces it to be. For example, another call to navigator.notification.confirm would then causes the queued message to run.

We've put extra logging into the NativeToJSMessageQueue on setPaused to see if something was not restoring the pause but it looks ok.

I'm sure we've done something to upset it. Is there anything fundamental that basically stops the message queue from being processed that we should be aware of ? Something that on the javaside would cause cordova on Android not to check the queue ?

We don't see the problem on iOS but I'm sure this is because it doesn't use the same message despatch system as Android.

Sorry for the lack of code or any more info. I was hoping this may ring a few bells.

**Update :**
We've done a little more debugging and it appears to have something to do with fullscreen mode. If set in fullscreen mode ( via the config ) or native code the events do fire. 
If fullscreen mode is set to false the callback event is left in the queue, and fired as soon as the button is pressed a second time.

```
function onConfirm(buttonIndex) {
    alert('You selected button ' + buttonIndex);
}

function testButton()
{
   navigator.notification.confirm('You are the winner!',onConfirm, 'Game Over', ["Butt1","Butt2"]);
}
```

Comment: Nice write-up, John. Did you ever find the solution to this? I'm having an identical issue, however my app is already full screen so I'm not sure if the work-around will work!

Comment: Hi Paul. I'm not sure we did. We left the app full screen. TBH at the moment to complete the app we have been focusing on the iOS platform and will retest on Google soon. We've also moved on from 3.3 cordova so not sure if that will make any difference. I fear it will bring another set of issues. Please update this if you find a solution ! Good luck.

Comment: I tried 3.5.0-0.2.7. No luck.

Comment: My answer got deleted.. Here's my feedback. This isn't an answer, but further details of the problem..

I tried 3.5.0-0.2.7 and had the same issue.

I notice this issue does not occur immediately starting the application. Changing pages once or twice seems to trigger it.

I also posted the query to the PhoneGap group:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/JojPoKSTdGQ

Comment: Raised this as a bug on Apache Cordov's JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7439

Comment: Thanks Paul. Will keep an eye on the report for their feedback.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in Cordova 3.6.0.